# Does qemu emulator have checkpoint function?

Tags: qemu, checkpoint

I am using qemu emulator for aarch64 and want to create an outside checkpoint (or fast forwarding) to save all I need to restart the system just from the point when I create checkpoint. (In fact, I want to skip the booting step) I only found something on qemu VM snapshot and fast forwarding, but it does not work for the emulator. Is there any checkpoint function for qemu emulator?

Answer (score 2):

A savevm snapshot should do what you want. The short answer is that you need to set up a QCOW2 disk for the snapshots to be saved to, and then in the monitor you can use the 'savevm' command to take the snapshot. Then the command line '-loadvm' option will let you resume from there. This all works fine in emulation of AArch64.

https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2015/07/06/tricks-for-debugging-qemu-savevm-snapshots/ has a more detailed tutorial.

Comment: Is it possible for the guest to tell QEMU when to take the snapshot?

Answer (score 2):

**Minimal example**

Peter's answer just worked for me, but let me provide a fully reproducible example.

I have fully automated everything at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/1e0f0b492855219351b0bfa2eec4d3a6811fcaaa#snapshot

The key step is to convert the image to qcow2 as explained at: https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html

```
cd buildroot/output.x86_64~/images
qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow2 rootfs.ext2 rootfs.ext2.qcow2
```

And the final QEMU command used was:

```
./buildroot/output.x86_64~/host/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -m 128M -monitor telnet::45454,server,nowait -netdev user,hostfwd=tcp::45455-:45455,id=net0 -smp 1  -M pc -append 'root=/dev/vda nopat nokaslr norandmaps printk.devkmsg=on printk.time=y console=ttyS0' -device edu -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=net0 -drive file=./buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/rootfs.ext2.qcow2,if=virtio,format=qcow2 -kernel ./buildroot/output.x86_64~/images/bzImage  -nographic
```

To test it out, login into the VM, and run:

```
i=0; while true; do echo $i; i=$(($i + 1)); sleep 1; done
```

Then on another shell, open the monitor:

```
telnet localhost 45454
savevm my_snap_id
```

The counting continues. Then, if we load the vm:

```
loadvm my_snap_id
```

the counting goes back to where we saved. This shows that CPU and memory states were reverted.

We can also verify that the disk state is also reversed. Guest:

```
echo 0 >f
```

Monitor:

```
savevm my_snap_id
```

Guest:

```
echo 1 >f
```

Monitor:

```
loadvm my_snap_id
```

Guest:

```
cat f
```

And the output is `0`.

Comment: I've converted ubuntu-16.04-server-cloudimg-arm64-uefi1.img using the above command, however, when trying to boot the new qcow2 image it ends up in:
UEFI Interactive Shell v2.1
EDK II
UEFI v2.50 (EDK II, 0x00010000)
Mapping table
     BLK3: Alias(s):
          VenHw(F9B94AE2-8BA6-409B-9D56-B9B417F53CB3)
     BLK0: Alias(s):
          VenHw(8047DB4B-7E9C-4C0C-8EBC-DFBBAACACE8F)
     BLK1: Alias(s):
          VenHw(837DCA9E-E874-4D82-B29A-23FE0E23D1E2,003C000A00000000)
     BLK2: Alias(s):
          VenHw(837DCA9E-E874-4D82-B29A-23FE0E23D1E2,003E000A00000000)

Comment: @hayesti arghh, so changing ext to qcow2 alone generates problems? I recommend this: 1) as a desperate attempt, try to install EFI as shown at https://superuser.com/questions/942657/how-to-test-arm-ubuntu-under-qemu-the-easiest-way and actually provide it to QEMU (not done there) 2) create a new question and CC Peter :-)